Найти обобщающее слово
Помогите, пожалуйста, найти обобщающее слово для мяса, птицы и рыбы (в плане еды). Не просто "животные" — надо, чтобы было в значении еды, покушать.
Уже около часа пытаюсь найти это слово. Я понимаю, что эти слова сами являются обобщающими, но должно же быть какое-то обобщающее слово и для них.
Слово "мясо" тоже не подходит, потому что мясо рыбы сказать нельзя....

Обобщающие слова надо искать для конкретного текста.  К примеру, подходит сочетание "белковые продукты". Текст такой: Белок в рацион человека может поступать из еды как животного, так и растительного происхождения. Белковые качественные продукты: мясо, птица, рыба и морепродукты, яйца, творог, йогурт без добавок.

"мясо рыбы"/"мясо птицы" конечно можно сказать, но как обобщающее слово мясо плохо подходит, потому что вызывает двусмысленность. Невероятно, но факт, люди не придумали обобщающего слова для мяса и рыбы как пищи.

Ни рыба ни мясо, нет мяса рыбы!  Даже мясо апельсинов есть, но только не мясо рыбы.  МЯСО, -а; ср. 1. Туша или часть туши животных, предназначенные для употребления в пищу. Заготовки мяса. Торговать мясом. Куриное м. Оленье м. Жарить м. // Разг. О говядине. Купить мяса и свинины.  3. Блюдо, кушанье, приготовленное из туш животных (кроме рыб). Подать на стол м.// Невероятно, но люди никогда не придумывают ненужных слов))  https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=мясо&mode=slovari&dicts[]=42

Мясо - это общеупотребительное название мышц с примыкающей к ним соединительной тканью (сухожилия, фасции а также кровеносные сосуды и жировые отложения) . Мышцы есть у всех животных, у рыб тоже. Спинные мышцы рыбы - это мясо. https://dzen.ru/a/YACYGU6RPxdY-Qhb. Удивительно, что это нужное слово оказалось ненужным, предлагаю Андрею придумать собственное название, глядишь закрепиться в народе

У меня даже теория появилась, почему слово не появилось. Потому что в Христианстве постятся большую часть года, и рыбу типа можно, а мясо никогда. Да и сложно их было спутать друг с другом, мясо это праздник, рыба тоже, только по праздникам. Это сейчас в кафешках доступно и то и то в любой момент. Но слова почему-то по-прежнему не придумали. Что там в английском?

Что подойдет Андрею, можно узнать только когда он скажет, в каком тексте он собирается употребить обобщающее слово. А если он этого  ПОКА не знает, то и слово ПОКА не нужно.

Вопрос нуждается в уточнении, не понятно, что вы хотите в итоге. Слова на выбор: плоть, туша, продукт животного происхождения, мышечная ткань...

Странные вы ребят, контекст был обозначен, это пища. Заходите вы в кафешку и говорите официанту хочу или рыбу или мяса. Не скажешь же дайте мне продукт животного происхождения, он тогда яйца принесет.

Обобщает не слово, но выражение "убиенная пища", если, конечно, не предполагается есть дохлятину

Второе (блюдо). Горячее. Горячие/холодные закуски.
Например:
Вчера у нас на второе/горячее была рыба. Сегодня - птица, а завтра будет мясо.
Из холодных закусок мы можем предложить заливные на любой вкус - из птицы, мяса, рыбы.

Вы вопрос не поняли. Человек хочет одно слово, термин для кулинарного обозначения трупов зверей. А вы целые предложения в ответ

если обобщить понятие мяса, птицы и рыбы выйдет - скоромное. Однако, вам по факту нужен гипероним понятия дичь в смысле мяса птицы. На Викисловаре такого, к сожалению, нет. То есть скоромная еда вам, думается, подойдёт.

скоромное это яйца в том числе
